# Alt text for duplicate images for SEO?

Tags: alt

i'm applying alt text to my images right now.

http://jamesngart.com/imperialairship.html

If you take a quick look at this link, its my illustration, along with it's sketch and 2 detailed shots. I also have a media query that shows another container that contains the same images in a different layout (for when window gets too narrow).

So essentially There is 1 main image, 1 sketch of the image, and 2 detailed shots. And each of these are repeated once. How do i apply alt text in this case without causing spam? If i type the alt text for the main image, should i copy and paste it into the alt text of the repeated main image (same file) in the smaller container? Or leave it empty?

And how do i treat the alt text of the detailed shots of the same image, leave it empty or copy and paste the text in?

Would appreciate some insight, this is my first site i'm learning how to make from tutorials, i'm not a coder as you can see haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only ever present one of the duplicated images, both should get the same `alt` value. Think of users that disable images: If you’d only include the `alt` value for the wide layout, users of the narrow layout wouldn’t get any alternative texts.

For the sketches: I’d consider these to be relevant content. If you agree, they should get a non-empty `alt` value. But not the same one as the main image! At least the alternative text should say that it’s a sketch, and ideally also include additional details (like which perspectives of the object are drawn; or whatever might be important in that context).

For the detailed shots: These could get an empty `alt` value, as they don’t convey any additional/new content. You might want to say something about certain details the shot focuses on, but if you do this, you should include it as text next to the image (for everyone), not just as alternative text (only for those that can’t access the images). An exception could be if the detail shot really shows something that can only hardly be seen on the main image; in that case, a non-empty `alt` value might be useful, describing the details.

Relevant HTML5 section for what the `alt` value should be for illustrations: [Images of Pictures](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#images-of-pictures).

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed reply. you explained very well. Thanks so much. 

For the detailed shots, I've considered adding more text to talk about anything specific in the shot, but it got too cluttered. 

http://www.jamesngart.com/imperialinventor.html

For something like this image. the 2 detailed shots are focused on one of the 2 characters in the main image.

But i would still not want to have text next to them. Should i leave the alt text empty in this case still? Thank yoU!

Comment: Sorry! one more thing. what about thumbails? http://jamesngart.com

Lets take the image i linked above for example. If the alt text for that main image is something like "Inventor creates clockwork gadgets aided by steampunk assistant"

Then the thumb on the index page that links to this image, should i leave it empty or should i drop the main alt text in there? 

Or modify it slighlty by saying its a "Thumbnail of Inventor creates clockwork gadgets aided by steampunk assistant"

Comment: @jamesngart: Yes, if you don’t want to describe the details, leave the `alt` value empty; otherwise you could say in the `alt` something like "Detail: the steampunk assistant holds a tray and pours some tea". ··· For image-only links (i.e., thumbnails), the `alt` value of the linked image [should not describe the image](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/48817/17023), but the link target! So it could say something like "Imperial Inventor, from the Imperial Steam and Light series" or similar. But if you also include the name as text (like you seem to do on your homepage), `alt` can be empty.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I'm clear on what to do now. appreciate the help :)